# Code Igniter SEO friendly URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, seo

I'm facing issues while rewriting URLs in codeigniter framework.

Here is my URL

```
http://localhost/article/lg-watch-urbane-vs-moto-360-a-detailed-real-world-comparison/19
```

And I've a controller like this :

```
class Article extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    $this->set_page_name( "View Article" );
}

function index($perma_link="",$id="")
{
    $this->response['article'] = $this->restutil->get("portal/articles/get/".$id,array('id'=>$id))->article;

    $this->render_view('articles/view');
}
}
```

And my .htaccess is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)$ /index.php/article/index/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I want redirect, all the request which comes as "article" to "article/index" function. But it is not happening currently. Only if i give "index" in the URL ie;
    http://localhost/article/index/lg-watch-urbane-vs-moto-360-a-detailed-real-world-comparison/19

Then only the page is loading. Otherwise it is not. Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: Here is a link I found with different htaccess files you can try https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter. As @Craig pointed out make sure you set up your routes http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to do this, with CI routes.

```
$route['article/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'article/index/$1/$2;
```

This should work. Re-routes anything that comes into article, to the index method.